# trying to restore full wordpress database

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to restore a full wordpress database from backup and I can't figure out which database is the one I want to get credentials for in the phpmyadmin portion. I've imported the database but there are four, and I can't tell which one I should put the credentials of in the wp-content.php file? How can you tell? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is file in your Wordpress website directory named as "wp-config.php". Open the file by an editor (like: Notepad++ or Sublime) and find the line like bellow -

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'dbname_wp710' );
```

Most provably you will find that in line number 23. Here my database name is "dbname_wp710". Now you have to find this database file in your backup and upload it to phpmyadmin.

Comment: thanks, but in myphpadmin there's 4 databases listed, how do i know which one it is inmyphpadmin?

Comment: All 4 databases should not be with the same Name. All of them have a unique name for sure. Please check all the Database Name and match with your "wp-config.php" file.